# BrowserSync from docker container doesn't work

Tags: mysql, reactjs, laravel, nginx, docker-compose

I cant run browsersync from container. please tell me how to do it right.
I built nginx, php, mysql containers using docker-composer.

```
version: "3"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx_container
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Php.Dockerfile
    container_name: php_container
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_container
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_container
    restart: always
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - ${PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Inside the container, I install laravel using composer, then change laravel to a bundle with react and install node_modules in the container.Everything seems to be fine. Next, I do `docker-compose up`. Setting up browsersync.

```
mix.browserSync({
        proxy: "localhost:7777",
        notify: false,
        browser: "firefox"
    });
```

After `running npm run watch`. The terminal displays:

```
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:7777
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.32.5:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

Addresses `Local: http://localhost:3000` and `Local: http://localhost:3001`are not working.
I don't know how to get this to work. please tell me.
My `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public/;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

My `dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  libpng-dev \
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  locales \
  zip \
  libzip-dev \
  jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
  vim \
  unzip \
  git \
  curl


RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/\*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www-data
USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

My `.env` file:

```
#PATHS
DB_PATH_HOST=./docker/mysql/database
APP_PATH_HOST=./src
APP_PATH_CONTAINER=/var/www/

#PORTS
NGINX_PORT=7777
MYSQL_PORT=33061
PHPMYADMIN_PORT=8765

#MySQL
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
```